# snap applications (kde) have no icons in the menu's

Tags: xubuntu, kde, icons, snap

I'm using Xbuntu 18.04.1 LTS and when I start the snap applications, they all work fine. But I've noticed only the KDE ones don't have any icons within the applications.

The error I get is:

Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed

Running with snap run packagename doesn't produce different results. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Oh, I've used both --beta and --edge with the same problem.

[image]